# How to take screen shot in iOS device programmatically for SOS?

Tags: ios, api, screenshot, photo, send

[image]Using new API's like

```
snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates
resizableSnapshotViewFromRect
drawViewHierarchyInRect
```

Using these i want to take photo in any format and need to send.

Comment: Since iOS apps are sandboxed, you will only be able to take a screenshot of your own app.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UIView *screenshotView = [[UIScreen mainScreen] snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];
UIImage *snapshotImage = [self imageFromView:screenshotView];

- (UIImage *)imageFromView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

Comment: By this i'm not getting the time stamp and signal strength on the top! Will i be able to get complete screen shot?

Comment: @DheerajChahar I have edited my answer, this will work

Comment: The image i'm getting is too large. It has main screen on the upper left side.

Comment: can you add that image, i need to see it

Comment: I have added photo on the top. pls check

Comment: How r u saving this image? I'm converting it to .jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116360/discussion-between-rahul-patel-and-dheeraj-chahar).